# Is it bad practice to use nullptr in ternary operation?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, conditions, null, logical-operator

I've set up a ternary operator in place of a pile of if-else's, the final expression being `nullptr` in order to finish the loop, like so:

```
int menuSelect;

std::string operation="";

(menuSelect==1)? operation= "string1":
(menuSelect==2)? operation= "string2":
(menuSelect==3)? operation= "string3":
(menuSelect==4)? operation= "string4":
(menuSelect==5)? operation= "string5":
(menuSelect==6)? operation= "string6":nullptr;

std::cout<<operation;
```

Is this bad practice? It seems to work perfectly well, but I worry it may be illegal in some edge-case (or otherwise flatly stupid).

Comment: `switch` would be more idiomatic

Comment: @Mat: Sure, but I'd like to know if this breaks any conventions. Can ```nullptr``` not be converted in my case?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. A ternary is an expression. Every expression must have a type. While it might look like the type could be `void`,  I'm pretty sure that expression actually has type `std::string&` due to the return value of the string assignment operator. That means the expression `nullptr` would be equivalent to `std::string(nullptr)`. Depending on C++ version this would throw an exception when evaluated, or fail to compile. A safer expression would be `std::string()`.

Comment: @amon Ah, thanks so much :) I was confused about where the conversions actually occurred.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a good idea because the ternary operator is intend to be used as an expression, and the recommended C++ core guideline is to [avoid complicated expressions](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-complicated).

Here you only use only the expression's side effects (assignment operator) and this practice has no advantage over a simple `if` chain, which is easier to read. Moreover, the type of the ternary expression is determined according [to complex rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) which would cause your trailing `nullptr` to be converted to `std::string` if the selected value is not within the given range, with all the risks that this entails.

A better alternative of this construct would be to have only one assignment with the result of your composed ternary operator:

```
std::string operation =
  menuSelect==1 ? "string1":
  menuSelect==2 ? "string2":
  menuSelect==3 ? "string3":
  menuSelect==4 ? "string4":
  menuSelect==5 ? "string5":
  menuSelect==6 ? "string6":
  "";
```

It's still tricky because of the priority rules, if you'd use something more complex than a string literal. Cascading `if` are slightly more wordy but much less error-prone in this regard.

Another alternative if you really want to be compact and avoid to repeat yourself would be:

```
std::string operation = (menuSelect<1 || menuSelect>6) ? "" : 
      vector<string> { "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"}[menuSelect-1];
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/4RbI2e).

(The last example is sheer provocation; in real code, I'd have initialised a vector in a separate statement instead of constructing an anonymous one, again, for readability purpose).

Comment: In real code, you'd use `std::array` rather than vector, of course.

Comment: @TobySpeight and static ;-) If the commands would not be constant and could change at every occurence, I'd go for the switch, in line with [Kernighan's advice](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/273375-everyone-knows-that-debugging-is-twice-as-hard-as-writing) and to avoid unnecessary computations :-) .

Comment: Oh, yes, absolutely.  Switch for me, too (probably in a separate function, so each `case` can be a `return` statement).

Answer (score 9):

In C++23 the code will not compile, as constructing a `std::string` from `nullptr` is explicitly disabled.

Before that, constructing a `std::string` from a null pointer (of type `const CharT*`) caused Undefined Behavior, and is thus most inadvisable.

Anyway, using a ternary expression as an if-else-statement is hardly clear, and certainly not idiomatic, thus should be avoided.

Comment: +1 for the c++23 hint.  It's  good news that compilers will flag the nullptr construction instead of letting it be a time bomb (maybe I should have more explicit than just raising it as a risk)

Answer (score 4):

Illegal? no. But it can provoke [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771938/1493294).

You're just looking for a default value when `menuSelect` is some unanticipated value. Any good reason `operation` can't be "undefined"?

When the unexpected happens you don't have to throw an exception. You just need a system that will gracefully deal with values that show our expectations were not met. It's why NaN exists.

Rather than null, often descriptive explanations of what was wrong with our expectations are best. In fact, it's why fractions, negative numbers, imaginary numbers, and transcendental numbers exist<sup>[=](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1696269/151778)</sup>.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this bad practice?

Yes, it is terribly unreadable. Unless your code is actually performance sensitive and you have profiled it, found this code path is the hot path, and shown this construct is significantly faster than readable alternatives, don't do it.

Comment: Totally agree. A bounds check and array or error handled map would be my go to here.

Comment: @LoztInSpace Indeed, this is what I showed as alternative in my answer.  It works well with literals, but the array could be more tricky if the operation would be build with more complex calculations, especially as all the computations would have to be made upfront.  As explained, a simple if chain could do (it would even be one byte shorter than op's code despite it would give the impression of being more wordy), and a switch could be the better alternative if there would be many more alternatives, in view of the jump-table optimisation ;-)

Comment: If fact, OP's code is not faster than a chained if, since the sequencing rules require to go through all the O(n) conditions one after the other. If nanoseconds would matter,  the fastest alternative would be a simple switch, thanks to the jump-table optimisation, which is O(1) as the vector approach but without the overhead.  Now it appears that modern optimiser recognises the pattern and generates jump tables for both approaches  [OP's code](https://godbolt.org/z/Wh63hKobW) vs [switch](https://godbolt.org/z/YnTacc5MM)  statement `jmp [QWORD PTR .L4[0+rax*8]]` line 28

Answer (score -2):

One problem doing it this way instead of a switch statement: You would use an enum and not an integer, and when you do that in a switch statement the compiler would likely tell you if not all cases are covered.

BTW. operator= “string” with no space on the left but one on the right side is confusing. Same with the ?.